# C++ fputs Assert on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: c++, assert, fputs

In the below code the fputs(...) throws an assert when running on Windows Server 2008.  I don't have this problem on a Vista or XP machine.  I'm at a loss as to what is causing it?

The assert is:  Stream != NULL

It seems to be random too, as sometimes it seems to succeed... as the log files get created.

Can anybody help?

```
void DLog::Log(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list varptr;

    va_start(varptr, fmt);

    int n = ::_vscprintf(fmt, varptr);
    char *buf = new char[n + 1];
    ::vsprintf(buf, fmt, varptr);

    va_end(varptr);

    if (!m_filename.empty())
    {
        FILE *f = fopen(m_filename.c_str(), "at");
        if (f != NULL)
        {
            fputs(buf, f);
            fputs("\n", f);
            fclose(f);
        }
        else
            ::MessageBox(0,"Error at fputs in Log","Error",0);
    }


    delete [] buf;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the second `fputs` that's asserting? Is it possible your `vsprintf` is overrunning the end of your buffer? Your format string and actual varargs may not match correctly.

Your question is tagged C++ and there are definitely better ways to do this in that language.

At least consider using `std::ofstream` to do your writing instead of the old C `FILE*` API. But better still is to forget the varargs function completely and using an insertion operator like the C++ standard streams. Then you get type safety and remove the need for easily mis-passed varargs parameters.

Comment: I like your idea, I'll have a look into that!